# Why lsof reports file descriptor of a memory mapped file as txt instead of mem on Mac?

Tags: macos, mmap, memory-mapped-files, lsof

I get the following output when running `lsof test` on Mac OS X, where `test` is the name of a memory-mapped file:

```
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
filesyste 40535 buildbot  txt    REG    1,6        3 2466028 test
```

Note that `txt` is reported in the `FD` field. However, according to the [documentation of `lsof`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/lsof.8.html):

```
   FD         is the File Descriptor number of the file or:

                   mem  memory-mapped file;
                   txt  program text (code and data);
```

So the question is: why does `lsof` report `txt` and not `mem` in the `FD` field?

The file is mapped as follows:

```
mmap(0, length, PROT_READ, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0)
```

where `length` is the length and `fd` is the descriptor of the file.

Comment: Interesting question, I never noticed this before.

Comment: Was wondering the same. Found this question of ServerFault: [txt file descriptor in lsof](http://serverfault.com/questions/548194/txt-file-descriptor-in-lsof) (it's about Solaris but the same explanation might be true here).

Comment: This is an older question but @DarkDust is correct. The logic is that mmap'd files are mapped to the process address space and, as stated in the output, `txt` is consider code AND data (the data being the mmap to the process address space).